# Variable in curly braces not working

Tags: bash, shell, curly-braces

I have a directory with country folders, where there might be folders that have doubled name:

```
 en_en es_es fr_fr de_de
```

And I wrote a script to remove the duplication:

```
 for code in en de es fr it nl pt tr; do
   if [[ -d $code_$code ]]; then
     mv "${code}_${code}" "${code}"
   fi
 end
```

But it doesn't work – the code under `if` never gets executed (I tried putting an `echo` there as well). However, the following works:

```
 if [[ -d es_es ]]; then
   echo "foo"
 end
```

I'm using (log)bash 3.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `$code_$code` is looking for `code_` + `code`, while you want to check `code`+ `_` + `code`. To do so, use braces: `${code}_${code}`.

```
for code in en de es fr it nl pt tr; do
   if [[ -d "${code}_${code}" ]]; then # <---- here (note also it is good to quote)
     mv "${code}_${code}" "${code}"
   fi
end
```

This happens because `_` can be present in the name of a variable, hence we use braces to  define exactly what is the name when calling them.

See another example:

```
$ this=3
$ that=4
$ echo $this_$that
4
$ echo ${this}_${that}
3_4
$ this_=5
$ echo $this_$that
54
```

Comment: Cool, that works! But why, what is the difference? (I will accept as soon as I'm allowed to.)

Comment: @janko-m Because the `_` is part of the variable name; `$code_$code` is the same as `${code_}${code}`.

Comment: @janko-m yes! See the difference in an example I just added to my answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is $code_$code.  The underscore is a valid character for identifiers, therefore bash is looking for variable `$code_`.

It can be fixed by using `\_` or `"${code}_${code}"`, latter preferred.

Example:

```
[root@TIAGO-TEST2 tmp]# for code in en de es fr it nl pt tr; do echo $code_$code; done
en
de
es
fr
it
nl
pt
tr
```

Using `\_` :

```
[root@TIAGO-TEST2 tmp]# for code in en de es fr it nl pt tr; do echo $code\_$code; done
en_en
de_de
es_es
fr_fr
it_it
nl_nl
pt_pt
tr_tr
```

Using `${code}_{code}` :

```
[root@TIAGO-TEST2 tmp]# for code in en de es fr it nl pt tr; do echo ${code}_${code}; done
en_en
de_de
es_es
fr_fr
it_it
nl_nl
pt_pt
tr_tr
```